# cummulative distribution function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The distribution function of a random variable $X$ is given by

$F(x)=P(X\leq x)$.

How to show that $P(X=a)=F(a)-F(a-0)$?

Is the following proof correct?

$P(x=a)=lim_{\delta \to 0}P(a-\delta\leq x\leq x)$ $=F(a)-F(a-0)$?

Comment: What is $a-0$ and how does it differ from $a$? In ordinary usage in mathematics, $a-0$ equals $a$.

Comment: $a-0$ represents the left limit

Comment: This follows from the usual assumption that cumulative distribution functions are nondecreasing and right-continuous.

Comment: How about you try some more suggestive notation? Engineers such as myself use $F(a^-)$ to denote the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the left and $F(a^+)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the right. For CDFs,  $F(a)$ is defined to be equal to $F(a^+)$, that is, CDFs are right- continuous functions.